# jQuery click listeners

Tags: jquery, lag, event-listener

I have a javascript file that contains every single jQuery .click listener code and I'm importing this file in every html that I need at least one click listener to be in. The question is since every click listener may not be in the html file, some of them wouldn't be able to connect. Would that cause any harm or lag?

Comment: It would slow your code down marginally through the extra byte size of the file and needless DOM accesses. Other than that, no problems.

Comment: jQuery ignores trying to bind handlers if the selector doesn't match anything.

Comment: ok then thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't cause any problems except performance when loading the page. All DOM modification functions in jQuery act as implicit `.each` loops, e.g.

```
$(selector).click(...);
```

is equivalent to:

```
$(selector).each(function() {
    $(this).click(...);
});
```

If the selector doesn't match anything, the `.each()` function becomes an empty loop. There's no error because of this.

Comment: I was looking for a way to detect if the div exist or not, this might work well thanks